# AWS EC2 Route 53 domain error temporarily unavailable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have an EC2 instance and there is a nodejs API on this server - I have successfully setup my load balancer and seems it working.

EC2: `http://ec2-3-139-78-144.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/api/version`

LoadBalancer: `https://filty-dev-api-279325829.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/version`

However, the domain that I have configured is giving me this error:

> (fitly-test.com)
> 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

I have also added to a conf file `fitly-test.conf` inside `/etc/nginx/conf.d`:

```
//fitly-test.conf

server {
listen 80 _;
_ listen [::]:80 _;
_ server_name fitly-test.com _;
_ location / {
proxy_pass [http://localhost:8080 _;_](http://localhost:8080;) _
_ proxy_http_version 1.1 _;
_ proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade _;
_ proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade' _;
_ proxy_set_header Host $host _;
_ proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade _;
_ }
}
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316851/aws-ec2-instance-routing-temporary-unavailable (Especially using two different logins!)

Comment: Quick check, write this command. `nslookup fitly-test.com` in terminal and see the response IP address listed maybe last one. check that IP is your EC2's public IP or proxy IP if you configured it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: thank you for pointing that out ... I was using to computer - the other profile was actually created for graphics .stackexchange and I guess they merge together and I got two profiles. But I have an email to merge these two accounts. Thank you